# MapServer Template

Tags: wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo, template

I have a wms mapfile to publish routing data line. Some of the lines have the same position and lie on top of each other, but have different values. I filter the objects with the attribute "classnr" to get different layers in the wms.
To get the informations in e.g. QGIS for every object I use a mapserver templatefile.

Now I have some routes with the same position, but different "classnr". They are in different layers, but if I use the identiy features tool in QGIS for one of the layers, I get the information of all other objects, too.
For example: In Layer_1 there are only features with the "classnr" =1, but with the query of the template I get informations of objects with other values of "classnr", if they have the same position.

How can I change the template that I can filter the query for the different values.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible with  a GetFeatureInfo template to do such filtering.  I think you'll need to look at your data query for your layers.

Comment: I agree that you should resolve the issue on the client side. Obviously QGIS is now making GetFeatureInfo query for all your layers `&query_layers=Layer_1,Layer_2,Layer_3,Layer_4`.